# Openapitools does not work anymore after update from springboot 2.x to springboot 3.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

When the gradle task openApiGenerate is executed the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)'
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createGenerator(YAMLFactory.java:479)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createGenerator(YAMLFactory.java:15)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.createGenerator(ObjectMapper.java:1164)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3742)
at org.openapitools.codegen.serializer.SerializerUtils.toYamlString(SerializerUtils.java:38)
at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.generateYAMLSpecFile(DefaultCodegen.java:7094)
at org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen.postProcessSupportingFileData(JavaClientCodegen.java:1129)
at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.buildSupportFileBundle(DefaultGenerator.java:814)
at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:917)
```

I tried to downgrade jackson but still the same error (although dependency tree says that the older version is used).

The task is defined like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$projectDir/$openApiDir"
    outputDir = "$buildDir"
    library = "template"
    apiPackage = "myapi.api"
    modelPackage = "mymodel.model"
    invokerPackage = "myinvoker.invoker"
    generateModelTests = false
    generateApiTests = false
    generateApiDocumentation = false
    generateModelDocumentation = false
    configOptions = [
            useSpringBoot3: "true",
            sourceFolder: "$generatedBaseDir",
    ]
}
```

Some hints how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs only if an other plugin is imported that uses a newer version of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem with spring boot 3, jackson-core 2.15.3, gradle and org.openapi.generator plugin 7.3.0. Problem was caused by the openapi plugin using an ancient version of jackson-core (2.12.x) under the hood for a any reason, despite its pom says jackson-core 2.15.3.

The following entry (in the root build.gradle of my multi-project) worked for me:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.3'
  }
}
```